# Add email url to gridview row, and open email window on double click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that has a column that contains emails.  I want the user to be able to double click the row and an email link is activated to open an outlook window for an email.  I've got the double click part down, but I'm no sure how to get the email from the row to create the url.  I'll paste the code I do have below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAllDOL" runat="server" Visible="False" PageSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="gvAllDOL_DataBound" DataSourceID="odsDOAll" OnRowDataBound="gvAllDOL_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="sintDistrictOfficeID" OnRowCommand="gvAllDOL_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvAllDOL_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:ButtonField Text="DoubleClick" CommandName="DoubleClick" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sintDistrictOfficeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="sintDistrictOfficeID" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="sintDistrictOfficeID" />     
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="vcharDOLOfficeName" HeaderText="DOL Office Name" SortExpression="vcharDOLOfficeName" />     
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="vcharDOLCity" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="vcharDOLCity" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="vcharDOLState" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="vcharDOLState" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="intBatchCount" HeaderText="Number Batches" SortExpression="intBatchCount" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="intCaseCount" HeaderText="Number Cases" SortExpression="intCaseCount" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="intExamCount" HeaderText="Number Examiners" SortExpression="intExamCount" />                        
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>


protected void gvCE_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "Highlight(this)");

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "UnHighlight(this)");

            // Get the LinkButton control in the second cell
            LinkButton _doubleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            // Get the javascript which is assigned to this LinkButton
            string _jsDouble =
            ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_doubleClickButton, "");
            // Add this JavaScript to the ondblclick Attribute of the row
            e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = _jsDouble;
        }
    }


protected void gvCE_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string email = ((Label)gvCE.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("lblEmail")).Text; (this doesn't work)


        GridView _gridView = (GridView)sender;


        string _commandName = e.CommandName;

        switch (_commandName)
        {
            case ("DoubleClick"):
                Response.Redirect("<a href=mailto:" + email + ">");
                break;
        }

    }     


protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow r in gvAllDOL.Rows)
        {

            if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation
                        (r.UniqueID + "$ctl00");
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation
                        (r.UniqueID + "$ctl01");
            }
        }


        foreach (GridViewRow r in gvCE.Rows)
        {

            if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation
                        (r.UniqueID + "$ctl00");
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation
                        (r.UniqueID + "$ctl01");
            }
        }

        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Comment: "how to get the email from the row to create the url" what do you mean by create the URL?

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi I need to get the email from the GridView so that I can add it to the the code like this Response.Redirect("<a href=mailto:" + email + ">");

Answer (score 0):

Convert your email field into template one. Add the following code and then try playing with it:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="EmailLink" runat="server" Text='Email' NavigateUrl= 
"mailto:" + '<%# Eval("yourBoundEmailFieldNameHere") %>'
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: I don't think you completely understand.  I need the email to open when the user double clicks the row of the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Manul's suggestion on adding the email address through an item template

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="EmailLink" runat="server" Text='Email' NavigateUrl= 
"mailto:" + '<%# Eval("yourBoundEmailFieldNameHere") %>'
</asp:HyperLink>
```

This way you can access the email address and people can see who they will be emailing.
then add this script to the page

```
$("table tr").dblclick(function () {
    var mailto_link = $('a', $(this)).attr('href');
    window = window.open(mailto_link, 'emailWindow');
    if (window && window.open && !window.closed) 
        window.close();
});
```

then remove the code that is adding javascript functions to each row in the grid, because it is no longer needed.

here is a jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/gorrilla/jEX7Y/

Comment: Is there a reason that this solution would not work for you? Though I offered the other solution. I believe that this is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command argument to pass the email address, greatly simplifying the logic necessary to retrieve the address.

Change the Command button column to an TemplateField and add a asp:button inside. Then add the attribute CommandArgument to the button.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="dblClick" runat="server" Text="dblClick" 
            CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
            CommandName="dblClick" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the code behind

```
protected void gvCE_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string email = e.CommandArgument;
```

Comment: I'm getting the error that CommandArgument is not a valid attribute of element ButtonField.  Is there a different way to do this?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry meant to tell you to change the command button to a regular button. Edited to reflect.